# Extract historic daily local temperatures from cities in the UK

Tags: python, dataframe, selenium, for-loop, webdriver

I have this data frame:

```py
            CurrentThermostatTemp DateAppointment
City                                             
Abergele                     20.0      2018-07-04
Abergele                     25.0      2018-06-21
Abergele                     21.0      2018-08-29
Abergele                     22.0      2018-04-30
Abergele                     19.0      2018-05-24
Abergele                     20.0      2018-07-04
Abergele                     21.0      2018-05-16
Abergele                     22.0      2018-05-29
Abergele                     10.0      2018-07-04
Abergele                     18.0      2018-05-09
Abergele                     20.0      2018-05-01
Abergele                     19.0      2018-04-17
Abergele                     21.0      2018-05-29
Abingdon                     22.0      2018-03-22
Abingdon                     20.0      2018-03-22
Abingdon                     19.0      2018-06-18
Abingdon                      0.0      2018-04-26
Abingdon                     14.0      2017-08-08
Altrincham                   20.0      2018-01-18
Altrincham                   25.0      2018-04-25
Altrincham                   20.0      2018-03-14
Altrincham                   21.0      2018-01-23
Altrincham                   18.0      2018-09-17
Altrincham                   21.0      2018-01-23
Altrincham                   20.0      2018-04-03
Altrincham                   21.0      2018-04-16
Altrincham                   20.0      2018-06-15
Altrincham                   18.0      2018-03-14
Altrincham                   18.0      2018-04-04
Altrincham                   21.0      2018-03-22
...                           ...             ...
Wrexham                      20.0      2018-04-26
Wrexham                      20.0      2018-04-18
Wrexham                      22.0      2018-07-10
Wrexham                      18.0      2018-06-04
Wrexham                      20.0      2018-03-05
Wrexham                      21.0      2018-03-19
Wrexham                      20.0      2018-03-26
Wrexham                      18.0      2018-03-29
Wrexham                      25.0      2018-02-27
Wrexham                      20.0      2018-02-05
Wrexham                      18.0      2018-01-15
Wrexham                      17.0      2018-02-01
Wrexham                      20.0      2018-05-09
Wrexham                      18.0      2018-05-02
Wrexham                      15.0      2018-02-22
Wrexham                      15.0      2018-04-20
Wrexham                      20.0      2018-08-20
Wrexham                      18.0      2018-09-05
Wrexham                      20.0      2018-05-18
Wrexham                      17.0      2018-03-07
Wrexham                      21.0      2018-04-04
Wrexham                      21.0      2018-04-05
Wrexham                      18.0      2018-06-15
Wrexham                      20.0      2018-04-05
Wrexham                      20.0      2018-05-30
Wrexham                      15.0      2018-05-25
Wrexham                      20.0      2018-04-18
Wrexham                      21.0      2018-04-09
Yelverton                     0.0      2018-06-11
Yelverton                    21.0      2018-02-22

[6159 rows x 2 columns]
```

I want to extract the local temperature of that day and city from the Internet via Safari’s web driver and I would like it to create a column to append it to the data frame. The page Im using for the testing is https://www.wunderground.com although I can use whichever I want. This is what I have tried:

```py
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import datetime as dt

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver import Safari
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

dates = []
cities = []
for index, row in Tempvs.iterrows():
    t = row["DateAppointment"].to_pydatetime()
    c = index
    cities.append(c)
    dates.append(t)
    for i in range(len(dates)):

        driver = Safari()
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 40)
        url = "https://www.wunderground.com/weather/gb/{}".format(str(cities[i]))
        driver.get(url)

        elem=wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//a[./span[.='History']]"))) #Press on historic data
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", elem) 

        selectMonth=Select(wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,"monthSelection"))))   #select month
        selectMonth = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("monthSelection"))
        selectMonth.select_by_visible_text(str(dates[i].strftime("%B")))

        selectDay = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("daySelection"))   #select day
        selectDay.select_by_visible_text(str(dates[i].day))

        selectYear = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("yearSelection")) #select year
        selectYear.select_by_visible_text(str(dates[i].year))

        View = driver.find_element_by_id("dateSubmit").click()  #view data
        avrgTemp=wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,
                            '//*[@id="inner-content"]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/lib-city-history-summary/div/div[2]/table/tbody[1]/tr[3]/td[1]'))).text #extract daily average temp from that day and place

        print(avrgTemp)  #have a list of all these temperatures to later append it to the dataframe
```

I have been getting many errors but the main one I get is:

```py
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Could not create a session: The Safari instance is already paired with another WebDriver session.
```

I am aware that this might take a log time to process but I am able to leave my computer in standby while its gathering the data.I would gratefully appreciate any help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

move `driver = Safari()`

to the top of the file ... before the loop after the imports